# An unknown error occurred: URL can't contain control characters

Tags: tomcat, ansible

I am trying to download Tomcat using Anisble playbook but it is give me this error

```
An unknown error occurred: URL can't contain control characters. '/apache/tomcat/tomcat-10/v10.0.4/bin/apache-tomcat- 10.0.4.tar.gz' (found at least ' ')
```

Please help how I can resolve the issue.

```yaml
---
- name: Install Apache Tomcat10 using ansible
  hosts: localhost
  become: true

  vars:

  - url: "https://mirrors.estointernet.in/apache/tomcat/tomcat-10/v10.0.4/bin/apache-tomcat- 10.0.4.tar.gz"

  tasks:

    - name: Update the System Packages
      apt:

    - name: Create a Tomcat User
      user:
        name: tomcat

    - name: Create a Tomcat Group
      group:
        name: tomcat

    - name: Install JAVA
      apt:
        name: default-jdk
        state: present

    - name: Create a Tomcat Directory
      file:
        path: /opt/tomcat10
        owner: tomcat
        group: tomcat
        mode: 755
        recurse: yes

    - name: download & unarchive tomcat10
      unarchive:
        src: "{{url}}"
        dest: /opt/tomcat10
        remote_src: yes
        extra_opts: [--strip-components=1]

    - name: Change ownership of tomcat directory
      file:
        path: /opt/tomcat10
        owner: tomcat
        group: tomcat
```

Need help to solve the issue coming on installing Tomcat from Ansible playbook ...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please format the code in your question properly so that it's easy to read. The simplest way is to [use code fences](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) that allow to also specify the code language.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

> found at least ' '

This clearly states that there is a whitespace in your URL:

```
"https://mirrors.estointernet.in/apache/tomcat/tomcat-10/v10.0.4/bin/apache-tomcat- 10.0.4.tar.gz"
```

However, the whitespace could be the consequence of an improper formatting of the code in your question.

What the real issue is, is that [`vars`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/playbooks_keywords.html#playbook-keywords) keyword is a dictionary, not a list. It should be like this:

```yaml
- name: Install Apache Tomcat 10 using ansible
  hosts: localhost
  become: true
  vars:
    url: "https://mirrors.estointernet.in/apache/tomcat/tomcat-10/v10.0.4/bin/apache-tomcat-10.0.4.tar.gz"
  tasks:
  # ...
```

Answer (score 0):

A minimal example playbook like

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    MAJOR: 10
    MINOR: 0
    BUGFIX: 4

    VERSION: "{{ MAJOR }}.{{ MINOR }}.{{ BUGFIX }}"

    URL: "https://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-{{ MAJOR }}/v{{ VERSION }}/bin/apache-tomcat-{{ VERSION }}.tar.gz"

  tasks:

  - name: Create dir
    file:
      path: tomcat
      owner: "{{ ansible_user }}"
      mode: 0755
      recurse: yes

  - name: Unarchive into
    unarchive:
      src: "{{ URL }}"
      dest: "/home/{{ ansible_user }}/test/tomcat/"
      remote_src: true
      extra_opts: [--strip-components=1]
      owner: "{{ ansible_user }}"
      mode: 0755
```

worked without an issue. One need just to adjust user and path for their needs.